# Is it possible to re-use an array taken from PHP via JSON in a $.ajax function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is the deal:
This area is a preparation for a dynamic chart where I'm opening a new select input when my first select input is selected. With its value(from the first), I'm doing a SQL query and getting the country data filtered by the first select. It is all working fine, but I do want to re-use this array which came from PHP to create up to 4 new more selects.
As it is staying inside the $.ajax success, I'm not sure if I can use it outside.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#indicators').change(function() {
      $('#country1').fadeIn('slow');
      var indic_val = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/chart_handler.php',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        data: {'indicator' : indic_val},
        async:false,
        success: (function ( data ){
            $.each(data, function(i, key) {
                $('#country1').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ key +'</option>');
            });
        }),
      });
   }); 
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "reuse"? You can define a variable outside the .change() call and overwrite it with the received and parsed JSON if that is what you want.

Comment: You can easily export data to a variable in a scope above the currently executing code in Javascript, because the current scope is inherited from the parent scope ad infinitum. All you need to do to share the data with another routine is declare a variable in the lowest common scope of both routines. Be careful though, remember that all your Javascript is executed in an asynchronous manner, it's all too easy to destroy data you still need because the order of execution was not what you expected. If you need to do this more than once, consider using a stack to store individual data calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty simple actually. Just declare a variable that is accessible outside the current AJAX call and is therefore persistent for that scope (inside the anonymus function inside the ready-function).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonData; // this is the variable where we will store the data
    $('#indicators').change(function() {
        $('#country1').fadeIn('slow');
        var indic_val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/chart_handler.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'post',
            data: {'indicator' : indic_val},
            async:false,
            success: (function ( data ){
                jsonData = data; //that's all what you need
                $.each(data, function(i, key) {
                    $('#country1').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ key +'</option>');
                });
            }),
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why initialize the outer variable to an object? Also, please explain *why* code solves problems ;-)

Comment: I always do that like this, perhapes cause I have to declare a variable with a type in other languages :) but there is no real reason for it. Added explanation.

Comment: Thanks. It was pretty dumb of me not trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create a function and pass the data as argument:

```
success: (function ( data ){
         myFunction(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, key) {
            $('#country1').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ key +'</option>');
        });
    }),

function myFunction(data){
  // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: It works as well, but I think I'll be using an array instead of a new function. Thanks though :)